# Drupal / nginx redirect domain without changing URL with proxy_pass

Tags: nginx, redirect, proxypass, drupal

We have a Drupal 8 website which runs about 18 languages, but only the Chinese one has a separate domain. We want this domain, which for testing purposes is testchinese.com to redirect in the background to drupalwebsite.com/zh-hans, where zh-hans is the language code for the Chinese version.

This is what we tried, it redirects, but the URL changes as well:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    #listen 443 ssl;
    #listen [::]:443 ssl;

    server_name testchinese.com;

    location /core/assets {
        alias /var/www/production/core/assets;
        try_files $uri $uri/;
    }

    location /zh-hans {
        rewrite ^/zh-hans(.*)$ $1 redirect;
    }

    location / {
            proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1/zh-hans$request_uri;
            proxy_set_header Host drupalwebsite.com;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name drupalwebsite.com;

    return 301 https://drupalwebsite.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    server_name drupalwebsite;

    ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/drupalwebsite.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/drupalwebsite/privkey.pem;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

    root /var/www/production;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html index.php;

    location /pMA {
        alias     /var/www/production/pMA;
        index index.php index.html;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location ~ \..*/.*\.php$ {
        return 403;
    }

    location ~ ^/sites/.*/private/ {
        return 403;
    }

    # Block access to scripts in site files directory
    location ~ ^/sites/[^/]+/files/.*\.php$ {
        deny all;
    }

    # Allow "Well-Known URIs" as per RFC 5785
    location ~* ^/.well-known/ {
        allow all;
    }

    # Block access to "hidden" files and directories whose names begin with a
    # period. This includes directories used by version control systems such
    # as Subversion or Git to store control files.
    location ~ (^|/)\. {
        return 403;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location @rewrite {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1;
    }

    # Don't allow direct access to PHP files in the vendor directory.
    location ~ /vendor/.*\.php$ {
        deny all;
        return 404;
    }

    # In Drupal 8, we must also match new paths where the '.php' appears in
    # the middle, such as update.php/selection. The rule we use is strict,
    # and only allows this pattern with the update.php front controller.
    # This allows legacy path aliases in the form of
    # blog/index.php/legacy-path to continue to route to Drupal nodes. If
    # you do not have any paths like that, then you might prefer to use a
    # laxer rule, such as:
    # location ~ \.php(/|$) {
    # The laxer rule will continue to work if Drupal uses this new URL
    # pattern with front controllers other than update.php in a future
    # release.
    location ~ '\.php$|^/update.php' {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(|/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        #include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    }

    # Fighting with Styles? This little gem is amazing.
    # location ~ ^/sites/.*/files/imagecache/ { # For Drupal <= 6
    location ~ ^/sites/.*/files/styles/ { # For Drupal >= 7
        try_files $uri @rewrite;
    }

    # Handle private files through Drupal. Private file's path can come
    # with a language prefix.
    location ~ ^(/[a-z\-]+)?/system/files/ { # For Drupal >= 7
        try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|svg)$ {
        try_files $uri @rewrite;
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

}
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Where you able to figure it out?